# Automatically set Teams status to "Do not disturb" at specific time/during specific calendar event

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-teams, focus-assist

Recently at work people keep calling me over Microsoft Teams during Noon-1pm, when I do online training sessions over my lunch break. I would rather have my status as "Do Not Disturb" during this time. I have an Outlook Calendar appointment showing me as "out of office" at these times but this does not help. I have also tried activating "Focus Assist" for these times but Teams does not seem to recognise this.

I can manually change my status to "Do not Disturb" each day but this does not really feel like a solution and relies on me consistently remembering to do this. Is there no way to set my status to "Do not Disturb" during a specific calendar event or at a specific time of day?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question of setting in outlook but settings in TEAMs. Directly in settings->notifications->calls and meeting->Mute notifications during appointments and calls.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1128177)

Comment: @Toto But it does provide a correct answer

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have upgraded your Outlook and Teams to the latest version. And set "Show As" as Busy when createing appointments in Outlook calendar, then teams will automatically show busy status when appointments begins.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Will this automatically block people from calling me? I don't think they are checking my calendar/status beforehand as otherwise they would already see that I am listed as "out of office".

Comment: Nope, according to my tests, auto busy status will not help block others from calling you. However, I did lots of researches and could not found a way to "Do not Disturb" status, if you would still like this feature, you could create a thread in Outlook User voice, then other users who have the same issue will could vote on it for you, Microsoft may notice it and add it in the later version. For now, I'm afraid that you could also change it manually as a workaround.